# Ordering queryset client-side, Django + TwitterBoostrap

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap, django-templates

I have the following:

## models.py

```
class Person(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(...)
    address = models.CharField(...)
```

## views.py

```
def all_persons(request):
    persons = Person.objects.all()
    return render(
        request, 
        'my_template.html', 
        {
            'persons':persons
        }
    )
```

## my_template.html

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead> 
    <tr> 
    <th>Person's Fullname</th>
    </tr>
    </thead> 
    <tbody>
    {% for person in persons %}
        <td>{{ person.full_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ person.address }}</td>
```

Ok, so the code as it is will display an unordered list of persons in the template, of course I can manage to order by Person's name or address, I want to give the user the possibility to order by any field, I want to accomplish this with a button on each column of the table in the template. For example a button on top of full_name and a button on top of address, if any of those is pressed, then the list should be ordered depending on the pressed button.

Thank you very much for reading, hope you can help me.

Edit: I use Twitter Boostrap 2, so tablesorter and DataTables JS wont work.

Comment: If all the data has already been sent to the client, why not just do this in Javascript?

Comment: Are you using django-tables2? If so, ordering is built in: http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/.

Comment: You have to create a button at screen and when the user click it, you runs a method the sort data, or just send an SQL to database and retrieve the data sorted

Comment: @user1775603 No I am not using django-tables2, but seems like a good module, I will take it into consideration.

Comment: Maybe you could convert `persons` to a dictionary and use this tag https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#dictsort

Comment: @Michael Mior: The problem is, I have not experience in Javascript, I was thinking about Javascript too, but can you give me some example of how to do it on JS ?

Comment: @Adrián López: Well the problem is not actually sorting, but dinamically sorting in the client.

Comment: Oh sry, so without sending a new request the only way is javascript imo

Comment: @PepperoniPizza [Tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) is more or less plug and play.

Comment: Try thi one http://www.allmyscripts.com/Table_Sort/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this JS plugin for HTML tables: [Datatables](http://datatables.net/). Comes with sorting, filtering, pagination, lots of plugins. Easy to get started, but you might consider it a bit bloated.

Another way is to have the view take an extra argument (an integer representing a field, for example), sort the queryset by this field and render the template.

Comment: I just checked that out, the problem now is I'm using Twitter bootstrap 2 and sorting is not supporte in Bootstrap, this is annoying.